# Tor on Apple IPad? Is it possible with only Cellular Data?

Tags: tor-install

I have recently bought an Apple IPad that uses mostly cellular data. I bought the device so I could travel with my husband on his semi truck and not have to worry about having a WiFi signal.

1st I am not sure what version of Tor to dl. I tried the IOS/Mac and it did dl but just disappeared to where, I never found??.

2nd And most important I believe, will Tor run without a WiFi connection?

I truly appreciate you folks being here to help for beginners like me! Thank you.

Comment: cross-post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/344258

Answer (score 1):

Tor on iOS is impossible! ...whether you use cellular data, WiFi or landline. :-p

[macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) and [iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) are two different operating systems.
Tor resp. TorBrowser is available for [Microsoft Windows, Apple MacOS, GNU/Linux](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) and [Android](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orfox/) (the Tor-equivalent on Android is [Orbot](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orbot/)) but **not** iOS.

there are some third party browsers in the app-store using Tor, but it is questionable how trustworthy they are! not to mention that most (if not all) are closed source.